# SQL Query for fetching data within a month or week according to timestamp column in table

Tags: sql

I want to fetch rows within month or week or today according to the timestamp column in the table. Please help me with a SQL query for that.

Basically, I have to add a filter for my data in PHP and jquery. The option value of Filters is Today, Weekly, Monthly, Overall. I have a column in my DB table for creation time. I have to filter according to that column. So, I need to edit my SQL query to get everything from the past month or week or day.

Comment: Do you mean get the data within a particular week / month?  Or everything within the past month / 7 days?  Basically, are we trying to find everything within the month of say March, or everything within the past month?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also be very clear about what YOU mean by "within month or week".

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get all records within the past 24 hours, week, or month, then you would need to do something like the following:

Past 24 Hours:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ExampleTbl
WHERE TimestampCol > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

Past Week:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ExampleTbl
WHERE TimestampCol > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

Past Month:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ExampleTbl
WHERE TimestampCol > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
```